# cannot setup vpython (videl for python) using python 2.7 and newer pyserial 3.4

Tags: python, pyserial, vpython

I am trying to follow an online tutorial that is a little outdated. But I like the instructor and how he follows his curriculum. He is using python 2.7 in the video and an older version of pyserial (2.6 I believe) that I can no longer find a download for. I went ahead and installed the latest python (3.7), along with the latest revision of pyserial (3.4). And both installed successfully without problems.

However the other IDE-looking program which he uses to code our scripts ("vPython or videl for python"), only supports python versions up to 2.7.9

This made me back-trace and also install an older revision of python (2.7) in a separate directory with python 3.7 still being installed in another.

Since the older version of pyserial is no longer available, I tried to install the newer pyserial 3.4 package using python 2.7 but every time I do it through the windows command line, it gives me an error saying "the module 'serial' is not available'.

This is already after I had extracted the pyserial 3.4 package into the python 2.7 "Lib\site-packages\" directory. And we can clearly see that the 'serial' folder is definitely in the 2.7 python library.

I'm wondering if it cannot install the module because of the differences in revisions or if it's because the command line terminal is defaulting to the latest version of python (3.7) automatically to execute the installation.

If this is incompatible, maybe someone can help provide a link to the older version of pyserial or help me find another solution to this problem.

Edit: I found a version of pyserial 2.7 but it is for 32 bit windows and not 64. I have been sticking to versions of 64 bit for python and vpython.

Answer (score 1):

So I found an older version of pyserial 2.7 for windows 32 bit. I'm not sure if pyserial had a 64 bit version at the time 2.7 was released because I could not find it. I uninstalled python 2.7 64 bit and replaced it with 32 bit, and then did the same for vpython.

This got the program up and running successfully and importing the serial libraries just fine.

The next problem was that the 32 bit vpython and 64 bit arduino's did not play nice together. And I could not get vpython to read serial data from arduino despite copying code verbatum and having it compile correctly.

My solution was just to use the pycharm IDE instead. It has a package installer that just downloads and installs everything for you. Thank god too because I spent around 3 hours trying to get the packages installed manually through the command terminal but kept running into compatibility issues like outdated published files, an annoying syntax error through cmd, a "not supported on this platform" error (despite pip and everything being 100% kosher) and not having microsoft C++ version 14 AND HAVING NO IDEA THIS RESOURCE WAS MISSING.

But pycharm solved all of that. Sorry for the somewhat salty response. I just hope it saves someone else's time. Pretty upset this wasn't suggested on any of the official websites anywhere.